# box plot analysis.

Tags: boxplot

[image]

I have been asked to comment on what I observe and I am unsure of what to say about not having 1 quartile for race 1, not having a lower whisker for race 2, and not having 1 quartile for race 3. I need help!

Comment: Try to plot the points into your plot and you will see the reason behind your questions.

Comment: It's worth noting that Tukey presented many different box and whisker plot variants in his original paper. More than one has been adopted as the standard and so you cannot be certain of the meaning of the whiskers and the 'outlier' points (a very unfortunate name, in my opinion) without some specification from the plotter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a quartile missing for Race 1 - maybe your 3rd quartile is just compacted betweeen a really small range of values (e.g. your third quartile is all between 3.9 and 4). I am not sure what software you are using to analyze your data, but it should have a way of counting values in a given range. Try counting the values above your median and below your 4th quartile (i.e. 3rd quartile values).

What is the minimum value for Race 2 RSESdiff? Maybe it does not have whiskers because there is not much difference between the minimum value and the end of the 1st quartile. Again, try counting the values.

Comment: The data are pretty clearly small integers